# How to tell if a uuid is standard or microsoft

Tags: c++, windows, uuid

Microsoft's CoCreateGuid and UUIDCreate functions currently create uuids that are variant 1 but dont store all the parts in big endian format.

boost when generating a uuid encodes the whole uuid in big endian format as it states in the standard.

if i take a uuid that was generated by UUIDCreate and pass it to boost's to string function it interprets it wrong because the uuid is a variant 1 uuid that is not stored correctly.

so how am i meant to tell from a binary what it actually is?

Here is an example:

```
#include <boost/uuid/uuid.hpp>
#include <boost/uuid/uuid_generators.hpp>
#include <boost/uuid/uuid_serialize.hpp>
#include <boost/uuid/uuid_io.hpp>
#include <Windows.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "Rpcrt4.lib")

void microsoft_boost_uuid_difference()
{
    UUID uuid;
    (void)UuidCreate(&uuid);
    RPC_CSTR s; 
    (void)UuidToStringA(&uuid, &s);
    std::cout << (const char*)s << std::endl; 
    RpcStringFreeA(&s);
    boost::uuids::uuid* boostUuid{ (boost::uuids::uuid*)&uuid };
    std::cout << *boostUuid << std::endl;
}
// f743c8b0-f8ab-4779-a9eb-a9db22682c25
// b0c843f7-abf8-7947-a9eb-a9db22682c25
```

as you can see, the same binary uuid has been converted to completely different strings depending on who reads it.

Comment: "*how am i meant to tell from a binary what it actually is?*" - you can't. However, it is possible to tell if a boost `uuid` is a Microsoft-compatible variant or not (see the `uuid::variant()` method)

Comment: @RemyLebeau so some people store it in big endian, some people store it in mixed endian. Neither of them use the variant field to tell you how it is actually stored like your meant too.
so when i have to consume both, there is no way for me to tell its format and therefore the real uuid

Comment: basically, yes. Unless you know the original source it came from, and what format that source uses.

Comment: @RemyLebeau that is really stupid. thanks your your help.

"you can't. However, it is possible to tell if a boost uuid is a Microsoft-compatible variant or not (see the uuid::variant() method)"

that function does work, but boost still encodes the whole binary as big endian no matter what the variant is.
microsoft encodes the uuid as big and little endian no matter what the variant is.

Comment: FWIW, see [this discussion thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4956142a-0a5d-4f1e-b102-93a3eea1b5d5/): "*Guid.NewGuid() ... uses CoCreateGuid() of ole32.dll ... Guid.NewGuid in practice generates UUID variant 2 version 4 according to standard RFC 4122, **but it is not guaranteed** ... CoCreateGuid API **which internally calls the UuidCreate function** the Microsoft Implementation also uses the random guid (Variant 2, Version 4) version of RFC 4122"

Comment: @RemyLebeau yes, i did see some of that. when i first read it i thought that the problem was that the generated uuid version and variant could change. The real problem is that they could change AND they also dont encode information in the binary telling you that it is infact a Version 4 variant 2. What is encoded is a Version 4 variant 1.

Answer (score 1):

`(boost::uuids::uuid*)&uuid` is undefined behaviour: `boost::uuids::uuid` is a different type from `UUID`. They return a completely different string because they represent completely different UUIDs (because Microsoft stores them with weird endianness)

You have to convert between the types manually. You can do this with a pair of functions:

```cpp
// Referencing:
// https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/guiddef/ns-guiddef-guid
// https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_79_0/libs/uuid/doc/uuid.html
// (UUID is a typedef for GUID)

// Microsoft stores the first 8, second 4 and third 4 bytes of the
// UUID together so that their bytes in big endian correspond to the
// bytes in the UUID. But the bytes are stored in little endian, so
// we need to change to big endian before interpreting the bits

constexpr UUID byteswap_uuid(UUID u) {
    u.Data1 = std::byteswap(u.Data1);
    u.Data2 = std::byteswap(u.Data2);
    u.Data3 = std::byteswap(u.Data3);
}

constexpr boost::uuids::uuid to_boost_uuid(UUID microsoft_uuid) {
    return std::bit_cast<boost::uuids::uuid>(byteswap_uuid(microsoft_uuid));
}

constexpr UUID to_microsoft_uuid(boost::uuids::uuid boost_uuid) {
    return byteswap_uuid(std::bit_cast<UUID>(boost_uuid));
}
```

(Where `std::byteswap` can be replaced with `_byteswap_ulong`/`_byteswap_ushort` if not using C++2b/`/std:c++latest`, and `std::bit_cast` can be replaced with a `std::memcpy` if not using C++20)

Comment: as i understand it from the wiki on uuids and the standard here: http://upnp.org/resources/draft-leach-uuids-guids-00.txt

the variant is meant to be used to tell the reader of the encoded uuid if it is stored normally (big endian) or in microsoft's odd way.

how, from a binary am i meant to know if microsoft has stored it strangely or if its all big endian?

Comment: @Gnomorian The UUID you've given has variant 1 (the variant bits are 0b10), the "standard" variant. It appears that variant 2 "Microsoft" variants are legacy and no longer used. I don't think you can tell from the raw bytes: Make sure you don't cast pointers and the type of the uuid should tell you how the bytes are stored (And try to serialize in one format).

Comment: the uuid i gave is the uuid generated by CoCreateGuid.
it is stored in mixed endian, but has the standard variant bits set.
this is my problem. if microsoft are storing all uuids like variant 2, if they are variant 1 or 2 and boost are storing all uuids as variant 1, how do i know as a binary consumer what the uuid is.
aparently the answer is you dont.